# jruby jar class loading errors: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jruby

I have a program that consists of a java half and a ruby half. When I compile the java half to a jar, everything works. when I just have the raw .class files, then ruby can refer to `SimpleStringProperty`, but when I refer to a java class that references `SimpleStringProperty` java gives:

```
LoadError: load error: designer -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty
```

I have been able to reduce it down to three files: one java file that references javafx, one java files that doesnt reference javafx, and a ruby file with the following contents:

```
require 'jrubyfx' # requires ruby javafx bindings
require 'my.jar' # I ommit this line when using the raw .class files
p Java::javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
p Java::mypackage.NoJavaFX
p Java::mypackage.RefJavaFX
```

When running with the jars in my cwd, I run it as `jruby -I . main.rb` and it outputs:

```
Java::JavafxBeansProperty::SimpleStringProperty
Java::Mypackage::NoJavaFX
Java::Mypackage::RefJavaFX
```

however, when I run it with the .class files in $CWD/mypackage/ as `jruby -I . main.rb` and it outputs:

```
Java::JavafxBeansProperty::SimpleStringProperty
Java::Mypackage::NoJavaFX
Class.java:-2:in `getDeclaredMethods0': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty
    from Class.java:2451:in `privateGetDeclaredMethods'
    from Class.java:1810:in `getDeclaredMethods'
    from JavaClass.java:2089:in `getMethods'
    from JavaClass.java:989:in `setupClassMethods'
    from JavaClass.java:97:in `access$700'
    from JavaClass.java:653:in `initialize'
    from JavaClass.java:694:in `setupProxy'
    from Java.java:574:in `createProxyClass'
    from Java.java:502:in `createProxyClassForClass'
    from JavaSupport.java:154:in `computeValue'
...snip...
Caused by:
URLClassLoader.java:366:in `run': java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
    from URLClassLoader.java:355:in `run'
    from AccessController.java:-2:in `doPrivileged'
    from URLClassLoader.java:354:in `findClass'
    from ClassLoader.java:423:in `loadClass'
    from Launcher.java:308:in `loadClass'
    from ClassLoader.java:356:in `loadClass'
    from Class.java:-2:in `getDeclaredMethods0'
    from Class.java:2451:in `privateGetDeclaredMethods'
    from Class.java:1810:in `getDeclaredMethods'
    from JavaClass.java:2089:in `getMethods'
    from JavaClass.java:989:in `setupClassMethods'
    from JavaClass.java:97:in `access$700'
    ...snip...
```

which leads me to believe there are two universes

I'm lost on what to do to fix this. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps your issues are related to [jfxrt.jar moving to jre/lib/ext](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-January/005677.html), i.e. in Java 7, javafx libraries are not on the default java classpath when running an application which has not been packaged with the javafx packaging tools.  For [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html), jfxrt.jar is on the default classpath, so perhaps you won't have any issues if you run with Java 8?

Comment: maybe, but, jrubyfx loads javafx for java 7 and I can reference javafx stuff from ruby and when they are in jars

Comment: Does your test case fail with Java 8 as well as Java 7?

Comment: Well, it fails, but on unrelated issues, so I cant really test

Comment: Try copying jfxrt.jar from jre/lib to jre/lib/ext